# LDAP expired SSL certificate

Tags: ldap, ssl-certificate, tls, renew, expired

The SLL certificate on the LDAP server expired recently, making it impossible to ssh into other Linux machines who relay strictly on LDAP.

Being a self-signed certificate, my understanding is that it cannot be renewed.

Knowing that I need to generate a new certificate, any ideas on how can that certificate be transferred on client machines when no remote authentication is possible because the old SSL is already expired?

Comment: It is *your* duty as the systems administrator to have a fallback to access the systems. Serial console (certificates are short and can be copy&pasted via terminal)? Local accounts (ones not using LDAP auth)? SSH keys? You can always boot the server using a live usb stick and put a new cert file in place.

Comment: Agreed, however this a level 1 PCI compliant environment, where you have only 2 options for authentication:
1. LDAP.
2. Physical access from single user mode. In my case those servers are in several parts of the country.

Comment: I feel sorry for you. Fortunately I don't (yet) have to deal with anything involving PCI. Are you sure kvm/serial terminal is ruled out?

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve the certificate on the client with

```
openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs -verify 10 \
    -connect '<host>:<port>' 2>&1 < /dev/zero | \
    sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' \
    > foo.pem
```

`foo.pem` can then be put in the client's trust store.

I'd suggest using a certificate signed by a CA though, even
if it is your own CA (easily managed with [TinyCA](http://tinyca.sm-zone.net/)).

The main advantage is that you can import the CA root
certificate and don't have to worry about trusting host
certificates anymore.